# Inserting in the middle of LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, time-complexity

Imagine you have a `LinkedList` insert elements {A, B, C, D, E, F}, these operation are *O*(1) now I want to go back to the beginning and add {G, H, I} so the final LinkedList would look like: {G, H, I, A, B, C, D, E, F}.

I could do this using `list.add(index, content)`, however this is vastly inefficient since each operation would be *O*(*N*). Later I would like to continue adding at the tail. I'm sure there is a way to do all these operation in *O*(1) time, without making my own linked list, I just don't know how.

Edit: So what I really want to know if Java have some sort iterator/pointer, i,  where a can insert from there in *O*(1), example to i=3 {A, B, C, ^ D, E, F}, insert {G}, {H}, {I} would make the list looks like {A, B, C, G, H, I, D, E, F}. 
`list.addAll` works but then I have to create a list first. Any way if such method exist I don't want to carry on without knowing it.

Lastly I'm asking this question to solve this Uva judge [problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=3139) I know how solve it, but if can't generalized other scenarios I'm learning nothing.

Comment: just use  `list.addFirst(   )` to add at first, and `list.addLast(  )` to add to tail and for middle use `list.add(index, data)`

Comment: `add(int index, content)` is `O(index)` not `O(list.size())`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html):

> Doubly-linked list implementation of the List and Deque interfaces.
>
> All of the operations perform as could be expected for a doubly-linked list. Operations that index into the list will traverse the list from the beginning or the end, whichever is closer to the specified index.

Regarding your concern:

> I could do this using list.add(index, content) however this is vastly inefficient since each operation would be O(N). Later I would like to continue adding at the tail.

This is not true. Inserting elements at the beginning or the end of the list is designed to have *O*(1) running time. Hence there is nothing to worry about.

---

Edit: After reading the UVa problem description, my answer above still stands. Furthermore, I'd like to add that a good way to solve the problem is to add entire strings of text at a time, not a character at a time. All the characters between two home/end keypresses should be treated as a single unbreakable string. Then we add these strings to the beginning or end of a `LinkedList<String>`, not `LinkedList<Character>`. There is still no need to worry about inserting in the middle, nor is it necessary to have an imaginary insertion iterator.

Comment: addFirst is O(1) however list.add is O(index), addFirst would not work because if you add {G, H, I} the list would like {I, H, G.....} more importantly imagine that I want to insert at index i and then at index i+1....i+s I don't to transverse all they way to i+s every time I'm inserting values.

Comment: @Yumario Not if you use [`addAll(int index, Collection<? extends E> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#addAll-int-java.util.Collection-). As in `List<String> list = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")); list.addAll(3, Arrays.asList("G", "H", "I"));` which creates list `[A, B, C, G, H, I, D, E, F]` and only had to search for index 3 once.

Comment: Thank you. Just to be sure java doesn't have some sort of Iterator to insert 'in place'.

Comment: What good would that kind of iterator do for you? It sounds like you only care about inserting at the beginning and at the end. Or do you need to insert in the middle? If so, please edit your question with a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Also: If you need a list data structure that is fast at inserting/removing/getting/setting at any index, consider looking at the [AVL tree list](https://www.nayuki.io/page/avl-tree-list)

Comment: @Nayuki I edited my question, if you can please take a look at it. Also I have seen you blog before, I quite like it.  Especially the lexicographical permutation, which I have use many times before.

Comment: @Yumario Thanks for the edit; it helps put the problem into perspective. I'm glad to hear you have encountered my web site articles before today's question.